# Wrong file installed when building a machine

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have 3 layers:

**meta-a**:

```
meta-a
└── recipes-my
    └── mypgk
        ├── mypgk_1.0.bb
        └── mypkg_rel
            ├── config.conf
            └── mypkg.service
```

- **mypgk_1.0.bb**:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}_rel:"  
SRC_URI = "file://config.conf mypkg.service"
```

**meta-b**:

```
meta-b
└── recipes-my
    └── mypgk
        ├── mypgk_1.0.bbappend
        └── mypkg
            └── config.conf
```

- **mypgk_1.0.bbappend**:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend_${MACHINE} := "${YOCTOROOT}/meta-a/recipes-my/${PN}/${PN}_rel:"  
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"  
SRC_URI += "file://config.conf "
```

I also have a `meta-c` layer.

- `meta-c` depends on `meta-b`,
- `meta-b` depends on `meta-a`.

Layers priority:

- `meta-a` = 14
- `meta-b` = 15
- `meta-c` = 16

Every layer defines a machine (`machinea`, `machineb`, `machinec`)

When I build `machinea`, the `config.conf` file from `meta-a` is installed.

When I build `machineb`, the `config.conf` file from `meta-b` is installed.

When I build `machinec`, the `config.conf` file from meta-a is installed instead the one in `meta-b` which have a higher priority.

When I build `machinec` I want `mypkg` from `meta-b` as-is, why bitbake use the other `config.conf` file?

If I rename `config.conf` to `config_b.conf` (changing .bbappend accordingly) in `meta-b` everything works as axpected.

**EDIT:**

`meta-c` content regarding `mypgk` is empty, i want it to inherit from `meta-b`.
in `meta-c` `layer.conf` i have this:

```
LAYERDEPENDS_c = "b"
```

`mypgk_1.0.bb` defined in `meta-a` is:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend_$(MACHINE) := "${THISDIR}/${PN}_rel:"

SRC_URI = "file://config.conf "

SYSTEMD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = " mypkg.service"

do_install() {
         install -m 755 -d ${D}${bindir}
         install -m 755 -d ${D}${sysconfdir}
         install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/config.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}/config.conf

         install -d ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
         install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/mypkg.service ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/mypkg.service
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
also copying `recipes-my/*` from `meta-b` to `meta-c/` doesn't work and `config.conf` from `meta-a` is installed

Comment: What is the content of `meta-c` and `mypkg_1.0.bb` ?

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM `meta-c` content regarding mypgk is empty, i want it to inherit from `meta-b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was the order of direictories added to `FILESEXTRAPATHS`.
modifing `mypgk_1.0.bbappend` in `meta-b` to:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_append_${MACHINE} := "${YOCTOROOT}/meta-a/recipes-my/${PN}/${PN}_rel:"  
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend_${MACHINE} := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
```

solved the issue